# mean of two matrixes with Nans, element per element

Tags: matlab, sum, nan, mean

I want to have the nanmean of two matrixes element per element. I don't seem to be able to do it using the function `nanmean`, since that doesn't sum element per element.

Simplified example:

```
A= [1 1 1 
    1 1 1
    1 nan 1];

B=[3 3 3
   3 3 3
   3 3 3];
```

Result I want :

```
C= [2 2 2
    2 2 2
    2 3 2];
```

So the nan is ignored.

One way to sum element per element I found on https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/366304-how-to-sum-up-multiple-matrices-element-by-element

```
A(:,:,1)=randi([1 3],100,100);
A(:,:,2)=randi([1 3],100,100);
A(:,:,3)=randi([1 3],100,100);
A(:,:,4)=randi([1 3],100,100);
B=zeros(size(A,1),size(A,2));
for i=1:size(A,3)
    B=B+A(1:size(A,1),1:size(A,2),i);
end
disp(B)
```

BUT this isn't the nansum. How can I do this not taking into account the nans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate the matrices along the 3rd dimension, then apply `nanmean` along that dimension:

```
C = cat(3,A,B);
C = nanmean(C,3);
```

(Of course you can write these two statements as a single one, I wrote it like this for clarity.)